# How to apply an animation on an item that is getting removed without using a timeout

Tags: angularjs, animation, angular

I'm using Angular 2 - RC3.

My problem is, I have an item which is shown or hidden using a *ngIf.
When the item is getting shown or hidden I want to apply an animation.

I'am able to apply an animation when the item first shows simply by adding a class. But the problem is when it's getting removed, the item gets removed from the screen before the animation can start/finish.

I know you can overcome this by setting a timer to delay removing action so that the animation can finish. But I don't want to put timers everywhere I need this functionality.

Is there an easier way in Angular to achieve this?

I don't want to use JQuery is either.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[hidden]** directive on your element, as it does not prevent the element from rendering like *ngIf does.

[hidden] mean it takes up space in your DOM document but it's display is set to : `none !important`.

*ngIf on the other hand removes the element from the DOM completly

Comment: what if it's an item that needs to be removed from the DOM. For example - when deleting an item from a list, to apply delete animation on the item being deleted.

Comment: Well you can do it by using css transitions with opacity going from 1.0 to 0.0 in 1second and then splice an item from the list. after 1000ms in a timeout.